# Is there a compound where one element has a CCP structure with all voids occupied by others?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

My Google-fu hasn't got me anywhere. All results have been quite fuzzy about it, nothing explicit.

Comment: Not quite sure what this is asking. If you tried to occupy *all* the voids, you'd just create new ones. Imagine you pour marbles into a box and try to fill the holes in the structure with more marbles---you'd never catch up with the holes you're creating!